# How to stop loading the data from the previous page in dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using true pagination this way:

```
<p:dataGrid  var="p" widgetVar="imagesDataGrid"
             value="#{pictureMB.tableDataModel}"
             columns="3"
             rows="12"
             paginator="true" 
             id="dgPictures"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
             rowsPerPageTemplate="12,24,48"
             lazy="true" >
```

What I want is when I select page two all requests that are for page one to stop (currently they continue because there are too big files that cannot be downloaded so fast).

Currently when I select page two , the data for the pictures on page one is still downloaded and page two is slowed down and cannot start it's request because the connection is busy. 
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop the browser from downloading images. Your best bet is to not use `<img src>` directly, but delegate the control to JavaScript who's capable of lazy loading images once the enduser scrolls to it. You could grab the [jQuery Lazyload plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/). It'll only load images which are visible in browser's viewport and not the ones below the scroll threshold. [See also the demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html).

Here's an usage example, provided that you've placed the `jquery.lazyload.min.js` file in `WebContent/resources/scripts` folder:

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="scripts/jquery.lazyload.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript target="body">$("img.lazy").lazyload();</h:outputScript>
    ...
    <p:dataTable ... var="picture">
        <p:column>
            <img class="lazy" data-original="#{picture.url}" 
                width="#{picture.width}" height="#{picture.height}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:body>
```

Note that the `<h|p:graphicImage>` is insuitable for the job as it would always autogenerate the `src` attribute while you need to set the `data-original` attribute instead.

Comment: This is not real solution for me because all pictures are displayed at first. They are just resized. There are not thumbnails (it could be decision yes but I cannot use it). And why I cannot stop the browser from loading images? When I'm changing the page or  reloading the same page , then according to my tests the browser stops to download the images. So may be I just can imitate somehow page changing with redirecting and  saving the curent page and page size as parameters in the session? Not real lazy loading but it could work ? Thank you! It's realy helpful answer and I'd come bach to it

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear from the question. I think it's better to use real thumbs then. You can use `ImageIO` to parse images to `BufferedImage` instances and feed them through and resizing tools like [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/). You could keep originals in DB and cache resized variants in server's disk file system and serve them with proper HTTP caching headers. You might want to reframe the question to get better answers on that. Otherwise I'd tend to just delete the answer.

Comment: No please. Your answer is perfect